# Embedding a Tumblr into a Website with the date

Tags: html, css

I am trying to integrate a tumblr blog into a website. I have tried a few various ways. I could not find out how to include the post date and pagification using the methods provided by tumblr.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://vicsavagetattoos.tumblr.com/js"></script>
```

This method does not allow for showing date of the post or pageification. I found a method that did on this web site:
Tattoosbyems.com

```
<iframe src="http://assets.tumblr.com/iframe.html 10&src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tattoosbyems.com%2Fpage%2F2&amp;lang=en_US&amp;name=tattoosbyems&amp;brag=0" scrolling="no" width="330" height="25" frameborder="0" style="position:absolute; z-index:1337; top:0px; right:0px; border:0px; background-color:transparent; overflow:hidden;" id="tumblr_controls"></iframe><!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('tumblr_controls').allowTransparency=true;</script><![endif]--><script type="text/javascript">_qoptions={qacct:"p-19UtqE8ngoZbM"};</script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://edge.quantserve.com/quant.js"></script><noscript><img src="http://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/p-19UtqE8ngoZbM.gif" style="display:none; border-width:0px; height:1px; width:1px;" alt=""/></noscript><!-- END TUMBLR CODE --><
```

I tried to implement this method by copying and pasting it into my test site and it did not work. I am not familiar with the php so I would like to avoid that if possible.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site that you linked is hosted on tumblr. Tumblr allows you to set your own domain for your blog if you have one--all the owners of that website did was associate their domain with tumblr.

The code that you copied is tumblr's code. What it does is generate the tumblr controls (Dashboard, Follow, etc.).

The first snippet that you posted is the proper code provided by tumblr. There is likely no way to modify it.

However, it sounds like you DO have your own domain, seeing as you want to embed your tumblr posts. You can simply associate that domain with tumblr and host your website with them.

Comment: Welp I am making a website for a friend. I am trying to get some web projects under my belt to add onto my resume. I made a nice looking portfolio site for him. He wanted a way to be able to update some of his work easily without bugging me. I advised using something easy like tumblr. He wanted it integrated like his friend whose site I posted. I have it working properly and well styled but he would like the possibility of including post date and pageification. I already paid for a hosting site, and a domain name.

Comment: @YoungGuy: Well why go through the trouble of modifying tumblr's code? Just install Wordpress in one directory (probably `/blog`) and let that worry about pagination and such. You can easily modify your Wordpress template to look like the rest of the site too.

Comment: I thought It would look tacky. I like the stream line look of having it integrated. I might try modifying the template. What do you exactly mean by install the word-press in the directory? I am using tumblr so are you suggesting when someone clicks the blog tab it redirects to tumblr?

Comment: @YoungGuy: Maybe I misunderstood, are you going to host the site on tumblr? Or are you going to continue hosting it on the host you've paid for?

Comment: I am going to continue hosting it on the site I paid for.

Comment: @YoungGuy: Most hosts have an autoinstaller, so find the one on your host and install Wordpress into any directory on your website (I'd recommend `www.example.com/blog`). Wordpress is a simple blogging tool (with an exceptional  GUI backsite to maintain the blog) that allows easy customization to match up with the rest of your site. Wordpress's beauty is that your entire website could be made with Wordpress, and only one of the pages be the blog. It's extremely customizable. So that we don't flood the comments here, I recommend you email me at the address on my profile for further assistance.